# Why Softmax is not selecting with maximum probability?

Tags: deep-learning, probability, recurrent-neural-network, softmax

I am taking lectures of course ***CS231*** from Stanford university. I am unable to understand the point from ***RNN***, Why Softmax unable to select the highest probability which is 0.84 for character **o** (in the attached example) instead of 0.13 for character **e**. Explanation will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Its probably a typo or mistake in the slides.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I disagree , also it's not only producing 'e' incorrectly but first 'l' as well.

Comment: You disagree? And what evidence you have of this? Its way more likely that the authors just made a mistake, as any other person. Anyways, what is the programming question here?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I am sorry I couldn't explained well, but i watched video lectures and the instructor mentioned it, but i am unable to understand from his explanation. Therefore I posted here to get better understanding of RNN and later implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really watched the lecture, but I think the 'e' at the top is the expected output(and 'l', 'l', 'o' too). The initial weights are not giving good enough results (giving 'o' instead of 'e'). As you train the network, the weights will become more mature and ultimately you will see the change in probabilities and the the first prediction will result in 'e' ultimately

Comment: Yes, you are right in general, but here instructor mentioned it's sampling strategy instead of probability. Thanks